# Image data is not accepted in my API trough params

Tags: image, api, flutter, http, dart

Hello I've been trying to convert an Image to base64 and send it to a specified API but whenever I post an Image, it won't accept the data, but when the image is null the data gets in. These are the example of the API data that has an Image in it:

```
"PostedPicture": "Images/Posted/PostPhoto_659.jpg"
```

And this is me trying to post it (Camera function):

```
 Future<void> _pickImageFromCamera() async {
final PickedFile pickedFile =
    await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
setState(() {
  this.imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
});
List<int> imageBytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
print("Disini imageBytesnya: $imageBytes");
image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
```

}

Api post:

```
Future<HttpClientRequest> postNewsFeed() async {
print(
    "Here is the post Type: $type, ID: $dataId, News: $news, SRCDOC: $sourceDocType, PRVCY: $privacyType, IMAGE: $image");
final client = HttpClient();
final request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(
    "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxx/Services/SocMed/SocMedSvc.ashx?Type=$type&strEmpNo=$dataId&strNews=${news.text.toString()}&strGroupCode=['$dataGroupCode']&strSourceDocType=$sourceDocType&strPrivacyType=$privacyType&strCreatedBy=$dataId&strEncodedImage=$image"));
request.headers
    .set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

final response = await request.close();

response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
  print(contents);
});
return request;
```

}

So basically I send the "image" to Params because the API uses params.

Comment: Please include the code for your API call

Comment: @Len_X Hi... Here you go